# Restrict Future Date Selection in Sitecore Form Date Field Type

Tags: sitecore-forms, field

I need Date of birth field in Sitecore Form and for that i used Date Control. But it's allowing selecting future dates also. Is there way to restrict user to pick date before specified date.

Also If there is any other OOTB control that can be used for Date of birth.

Comment: which Sitecore version you are using? And do you have form extension?